# Cannot deploy Spring boot application to Wildfly 8.2 in eclipse

Tags: spring, spring-boot, wildfly-8

I am trying to deploy a spring boot application to Wildfly 8.2 in eclipse. The logs say that the application is deployed, but I don't see the logs of the actual spring boot application starting up and it is unreachable.

```
    @PropertySources({@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties"),ignoreResourceNotFound = true)})   
    @ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.open"})
    @EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.open.common.entity"})
    @SpringBootApplication
        public class PfApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

            public static void main(String[] args) {
                SpringApplication.run(PfApplication.class, args);
            }

            @Override
            protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
                return application.sources(PfApplication.class);
            }
        }
```

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.open</groupId>
    <artifactId>web-services</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.open</groupId>
        <artifactId>open-platform</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.7</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- Spring Jars -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Swagger documentation -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- HikariCP DS -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
            <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hazelcast -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.hazelcast</groupId>
            <artifactId>hazelcast-spring</artifactId>
            <version>3.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Excel -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.10.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.10.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- open dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.open</groupId>
            <artifactId>services</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.open</groupId>
            <artifactId>common</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Parent Pom:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.open</groupId>
    <artifactId>open-platform</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.7</java.version>
    </properties>
    <modules>
        <module>web-services</module>
        <module>web</module>
        <module>services</module>
        <module>dao</module>
        <module>database</module>
        <module>common</module>
    </modules>
</project>
```

Logs:

```
20:19:16,746 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 1.3.3.Final
20:19:17,214 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] (main) JBoss MSC version 1.2.2.Final
20:19:17,370 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS015899: WildFly 8.2.1.Final "Tweek" starting
20:19:19,353 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS015003: Found web-services.war in deployment directory. To trigger deployment create a file called web-services.war.dodeploy
20:19:19,385 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015888: Creating http management service using socket-binding (management-http)
20:19:19,401 INFO  [org.xnio] (MSC service thread 1-8) XNIO version 3.3.0.Final
20:19:19,417 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] (MSC service thread 1-8) XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.3.0.Final
20:19:19,463 WARN  [org.jboss.as.txn] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 46) JBAS010153: Node identifier property is set to the default value. Please make sure it is unique.
20:19:19,463 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 45) JBAS013171: Activating Security Subsystem
20:19:19,495 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 47) JBAS017502: Undertow 1.1.8.Final starting
20:19:19,495 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS017502: Undertow 1.1.8.Final starting
20:19:19,510 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 32) JBAS010280: Activating Infinispan subsystem.
20:19:19,541 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 27) JBAS010403: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class org.h2.Driver (version 1.3)
20:19:19,573 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 48) JBAS015537: Activating WebServices Extension
20:19:19,588 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.logging] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS010408: Starting JCA Subsystem (IronJacamar 1.1.9.Final)
20:19:19,619 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 40) JBAS011800: Activating Naming Subsystem
20:19:19,635 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS010417: Started Driver service with driver-name = h2
20:19:19,635 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jsf] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 38) JBAS012615: Activated the following JSF Implementations: [main]
20:19:19,682 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS011802: Starting Naming Service
20:19:19,682 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS013170: Current PicketBox version=4.0.21.Final
20:19:19,713 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.io] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 31) WFLYIO001: Worker 'default' has auto-configured to 8 core threads with 64 task threads based on your 4 available processors
20:19:19,853 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015400: Bound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
20:19:19,885 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 47) JBAS017527: Creating file handler for path C:\x\wildfly-8.2.1.Final/welcome-content
20:19:19,916 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS017525: Started server default-server.
20:19:19,916 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBoss Remoting version 4.0.7.Final
20:19:20,354 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS017531: Host default-host starting
20:19:20,998 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS017519: Undertow HTTP listener default listening on localhost/127.0.0.1:8080
20:19:21,154 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS010400: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
20:19:21,232 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "web-services.war" (runtime-name: "web-services.war")
20:19:21,248 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS015012: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory C:\x\wildfly-8.2.1.Final\standalone\deployments
20:19:21,731 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBWS022052: Starting JBoss Web Services - Stack CXF Server 4.3.2.Final
20:19:22,594 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS017534: Registered web context: /web-services
20:19:22,688 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 28) JBAS018559: Deployed "web-services.war" (runtime-name : "web-services.war")
20:19:22,719 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015961: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990/management
20:19:22,719 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015951: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
20:19:22,719 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015874: WildFly 8.2.1.Final "Tweek" started in 6383ms - Started 249 of 304 services (92 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
```

Using JDK 1.7.0.79

Also, when I import the maven project, it does not automatically recognize it as a dynamic web module, I have to add that project facet.

Lastly, this project has no web.xml file, because of the spring boot config. (I also tried deploying with a web.xml file, but had the same result)

Comment: There was actually someting wrong with my eclipse. I think it may have something to do with accidentally opening the project in 2 different versions of eclipse. I'm not sure. But I downloaded a fresh copy of eclipse and everything seemed to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I see some differences in your `PFApplication` versus the example one listed in a spring blog on [Deploying Spring Boot Applications](https://spring.io/blog/2014/03/07/deploying-spring-boot-applications#what-about-the-java-ee-application-server). A little more extensive than can be listed here, but the example main class is thus:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(applicationClass, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(applicationClass);
    }

    private static Class<Application> applicationClass = Application.class;
}
```

See the blog for finer points like configuring your pom.xml for wildfly.

Comment: Sorry, that was omitted. I will update the question to show this.